# Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, arrays, select

I'm trying to select a value from a database and display it to the user using SELECT. However I keep getting this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in (pathname) on line 36.
```

I thought that the `@mysql_fetch_assoc();` would fix this but I still get the notice. This is the part of the code where I'm getting the error:

```
  {
  $loggedin = 1;

  $get = @mysql_query("SELECT money FROM players WHERE username = 
 '$_SESSION[username]'");
  $money = @mysql_fetch_assoc($get);

  echo '<p id= "status">'.$_SESSION['username'].'<br>
  Money: '.$money.'.
  </p>';
  }
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty new to PHP.

Comment: As Razvan pointed out, you're trying to echo an array. It doesn't work that way. Try running `print_r($money);` to see what your array contains.

Comment: You're retrieving a *result set* from the database into `$money`. How can you echo it directly which is an array. Why don't you use a loop to iterate over the array and echo the required fields within the loop?

Comment: When I use print_r, instead of a number it prints Resource Id #4.

Comment: @Sunden:) Put it into a loop something like this `while($money = @mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){echo $money['money'];}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that $money is an array and you are treating it like a string or a variable which can be easily converted to string. You should say something like:

```
 '.... Money:'.$money['money']
```

Comment: That get rids of the notice but the money value does not show up in the echo, it's just blank.

Comment: For the record, in comments below the question OP tells us it's a Resource. The solution is then to iterate over the resource. Key-access on a resource as in this accepted answer probably does not work. So this answer "$money is an array" is wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
$get = @mysql_query("SELECT money FROM players WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'");
```

note the quotes around *username* in the **$_SESSION** reference.

Comment: Finally I understood where I did a type, good advice about how to work with arrays ;)

Answer (score 1):

One of reasons why you will get this Notice: Array to string conversion in… is that you are combining group of arrays. Example, sorting out several first and last names.

To echo elements of array properly, you can use the function, `implode(separator, array)`
Example:

```
implode(' ', $var)
```

result:

```
first name[1], last name[1]
first name[2], last name[2]
```

More examples from [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Store the Value of $_SESSION['username'] into a variable such as $username

```
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

$get = @mysql_query("SELECT money FROM players WHERE username = 
 '$username'");
```

it should work!

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_assoc returns an array so you can not echo an array, need to print_r() otherwise particular string $money['money'].

Answer (score 0):

You cannot echo an array. 
Must use print_r instead.

```
<?php
$result = $conn->query("Select * from tbl");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
print_r ($row);
?>
```