# 1000 User GCM: Array to String Conversion Error

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to send batched GCM messages in blocks of 1000. However, the below code returns the error
`Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 651`

on line: `echo updateDataGCM($db);` within the action:

```
case "sendGroupMessage":
        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password, $gcmregid)) 
        {   
            if (isset($_REQUEST['toGroupId']))
            {   // instead of toUserName it's to a groupId
                $toGroupName = $_REQUEST['toGroupName'];
                $toGroupId   = $_REQUEST['toGroupId'];  
                $message     = $_REQUEST['messageText'];
                $campaign    = $_REQUEST['campaign_id'];
                $location    = $_REQUEST['location_id'];

                // Query to get the users id's who are in the group but not the user sending the message        
                $sqlGroupMembers = "SELECT DISTINCT usersId from users_groups 
                     WHERE usersId != '".$userId."' AND groupId = '".$toGroupId."'";


                // Loop to create a copy of message for all users taht are part of that group
                if($getGroupMembersId = $db->query($sqlGroupMembers)) 
                {
                    while($rowGroupMembers = $db -> fetchObject($getGroupMembersId))
                    {
                        $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `group_messages`...";                     

                        error_log("$sql22", 3 , "error_log");
                        if ($db->query($sql22)) 
                        {

                            $out = SUCCESSFUL;

                        }               
                        else 
                        {
                            $out = FAILED;
                        }                   

                    }               


                }

                // Send GCM to turn on devices:
                echo updateDataGCM($db);    

            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }           

        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;
```

The updateDataGCM() function:

```
function updateDataGCM($db) {
    // Get all the GCM regIDs for anyone with new, "unseen" data:
    $sqlAllRegIds = 'select distinct gcm_registration_id 
                    from users';

    // Execute
    if ($resultIds = $db->query($sqlAllRegIds)) 
    {
        $gcmRegIds = array();
        $i = 0;
        while($query_row = $db -> fetchObject($resultIds)) {
            $i++;
            $gcmRegIds[floor($i/1000)][] = $query_row;
        }

        $pushMessage = $_POST["syncNewData"];   
        $message = array("syncNewData" => $pushMessage);
        $pushStatus = array();
        foreach($gcmRegIds as $val) $pushStatus[] = sendPushNotificationToGCM($val, $message);
        return $pushStatus; 
    }   

}
```

How can I get this to send the GCM messages properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notice: Array to string conversion in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596693/notice-array-to-string-conversion-in)

Comment: This has to do with executing gcm in batches, not explicitly php arrays

Comment: This has everything to do with PHP arrays. Read the error message properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in your code indicates that the GCM isn't sending properly; so we can't help you there.

However, it is indicating that you're trying to echo the return value of the `updateDataGCM` function which is the array `$pushStatus;` which you've returned from that function with `return $pushStatus;`.

In order to know what you're working with, you should use `gettype($var)`, and also always `var_dump($var);` at the very minimum.

**Sidenote**

You should have a [read about Making the most of Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html). There are things such as rate limits, as well as quality control, which may impede your ability to send out 1000's of GCM's (which its self doesn't really make any sense.)