# Notice: Array to string conversion in F:\xampp\htdocs\digikalamvc\views\admin\product\addproduct.php on line 84 Array

Tags: php, xampp

I know there were some questions related to this, but there are mysql or other languages. I get this error and I'm not sure what's wrong with my function. This is my Error

> Notice:  Array to string conversion in
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\digikalamvc\views\admin\product\addproduct.php on line
>   84 Array :`<input type="text" name="title" value="<?= $productInfo = ['title']; ?>">`

---

And my function is`enter code here`

```
<?php

require('views/admin/layout.php');

$productInfo = $data['productInfo'];

?>


<form action="adminproduct/addproduct" method="post">

    <div class="row">

        <span class="span_title">
عنوان محصول:
        </span>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="<?= $productInfo = ['title']; ?>">

    </div>
```

Comment: Too much not related code posted..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notice: Array to string conversion in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596693/notice-array-to-string-conversion-in)

Comment: `<?= $productInfo = ['title']; ?>` You create an array `['title']` and assign it to a variable `$productInfo` which you then are trying to echo. You can't echo arrays. If you do, you'll get _"Notice: Array to string conversion"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors on line 84 and on other lines.
Look up similar codes like:

```
<?= $productInfo = ['title']; ?>
```

and change it to

```
<?= $productInfo['title']; ?>
<?= $productInfo['price']; ?>
etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump();

print_f();
```

84 line array variable add

results report pls

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?= $productInfo = ['title']; ?>">
```

change

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<? echo $productInfo['title']; ?>">
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $productInfo['title']; ?>">
```

array tree

```
<?php echo var_dump($productInfo); ?>
```