# How to rezolve this error in PHPf for sotring probleme

Tags: php, sorting, insertion-sort

I've tried to make a apply a simple sorting technique like Insertion method, and I've got this annoying error.
I'm using PHP 7.

```
<br />
<b> Notice:  Array to string conversion in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>21</b><br /> Array
```

The line 21 is where I call echo Interschimbare

The code is as following:

```
<?php
function Interschimbare(array $Vector) : array{
  $N = count($Vector);
for($i = 0; $i < $N - 1; $i++)
{
    for($j = $i + 1; $j < $N; $j++)
    {
        if($Vector[$i] > $Vector[$j])
        {
            $aux = $Vector[$i];
            $Vector[$i] = $Vector[$j];
            $Vector[$j] = $aux;
        }
    }
}
return $Vector;
}

$test = [3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1];

//print_r(Interschimbare($test)); // with this line works just fine
echo Interschimbare($test);
```

With `echo` doesn't work but with `print_r` works just fine

Comment: echo is used to print strings, not arrays and your array ain't a string.

Comment: You can use implode to echo the array. https://3v4l.org/RdVUC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to echo an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816889/how-to-echo-an-array-in-php)

Comment: https://ideone.com/tpY9oq (see stderr for the warning, plus it is completely independent from the sorting part).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notice: Array to string conversion in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596693/notice-array-to-string-conversion-in)

Comment: use `echo json_encode(Interschimbare($test));`

Answer (score 0):

:)
your variable `$Vector` is an array so you need to convert it to string in order to use echo.

for example:

```
echo implode(",",Interschimbare($test));
```

output will be:

```
-1,0,1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: nice :) up vote my answer (by pressing arrow up) so other users can easily identify correct answer :)